# Anchor and passing multiple query strings

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send an email with a link that contains multiple query strings. However i am getting an error that  ";" expected near Eval.

bodyText is the body of the email that i am trying to send.

This is what i have tried.

```
 bodyText = bodyText + "Please Click '<a href=http://urlpath/Default.aspx?param1=<%#Eval("p1")%>&param2=<%#Eval("p2")%>'Here</a> to view results"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
bodyText += <%# String.Format("Please Click <a href=\"http://urlpath/Default.aspx?param1{0}&param2={1}\">Here</a> to view results", Eval("p1"), Eval("p2")) %>
```

Use `String.Format()` for clarity and mind double quotes for HTML attributes.

Comment: This worked great..since i am doing code behind,  i didnt need the initial opening and closing tag..(<%#) Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it the problem but your tag is not formated correctly 
should be like

```
bodyText = bodyText + "Please Click '<a href='http://urlpath/Default.aspx?param1=<%#Eval("p1")%>&param2=<%#Eval("p2")%>'>Here</a> to view results"
```

Comment: i probably made an error during submission..that does not help..i still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the embedded double quote characters:

```
bodyText = bodyText + "Please Click '<a href=http://urlpath/Default.aspx?param1=<%#Eval(\"p1\")%>&param2=<%#Eval(\"p2\")%>'Here</a> to view results"
```

Comment: escaping double quotes does not throw an error but the email i am getting is like this Please Click '&param2='>Here to view results